Why are my changes to proxy.conf.js not being applied?
I'm working on an application for personal use, and I decided to use this as an opportunity to learn Angular. I'm using .NET 8 for the backend, and I created the project using the "Angular and ASP.NET Core" option in Visual Studio.
The problem I'm having is that changes to my proxy.conf.js aren't being applied. This is making it impossible for me to hit different endpoints being served by the backend.
The reason I suspect that my changes to proxy.conf.js aren't being applied is because even if I remove everything from this file, the example endpoint Visual Studio creates /weatherforecast still works. That is, even though I should have no proxies configured at all (since the file is empty), hitting https://localhost:4200/weatherforecast still serves up the content from https://localhost:7028/weatherforecast (but with the URL https://localhost:4200/weatherforecast).
Changes I've made to other files are being applied, since I can see them being reflected in the browser. Specifically, the other files I made changes to were app.component.html and app.component.ts.
I'm really at a loss as to what's going on here. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if there's some weird bug happening here. I've tried searching online to no success.
I've tried the following:

Rebuilding in Visual Studio
Running ng build on the command line
Doing a complete clean in Visual Studio, closing it, reopening it, and then doing another rebuild
Searching my whole solution for "weatherforecast" to see if there was some other proxy or configuration file I was missing

Since I'm still new to angular, I'm not sure which files are helpful to include, but based on some other similar questions I've included the following below:

Contents of proxy.conf.js
Contents of angular.json
Screenshot of my file directory

Here is my proxy.conf.js file:
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/session"
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:7028",
    secure: false
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;

and here is my angular.json file:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "pcm.client": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/pcm.client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "pcm.client:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "pcm.client:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "pcm.client:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "26a9eae7-d631-4c1a-a9b8-749d327af4a5"
  }
}

and here is a screenshot of my file directory:


After my investigation, when we click the Start Button in vs2022. It will shows 2 command line windows in the task bar.


And if we click the Stop button in  vs2022. Then we can found the webapi project is no longer  working, but angular project can.

So we have to manually terminate the angular command window, then modify the proxy.conf.js file, and we can find it will take effect.
